# Negative time_point

Tags: c++, c++11

Is a negative time_point allowed or it is just my implementation that allows this ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;
using namespace chrono;

int main()
{
    using sc_tp = steady_clock::time_point;
    using sc_dur = steady_clock::duration;
    sc_tp tp( sc_dur( -1 ) );
    cout << tp.time_since_epoch().count() << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`std::chrono::nanoseconds`, `std::chrono::microseconds` etc. are specified to be stored in a [signed integer type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration) but `std::chrono::steady_clock` only specifies [the duration uses an arithmetic type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock). Every implementation I've seen uses one of the chrono helper duration types for `steady_clock::duration` but there is nothing in the standard requiring that to be the case so it could use an unsigned duration.

Note (thanks to Howard Hinnant) that `std::chrono::system_clock` does [specify that the duration uses a signed type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/system_clock).

Comment: Trivia:  `system_clock::rep` is required to be signed: http://eel.is/c++draft/time.clock.system#members-1 (but not `steady_clock::rep` as you correctly state).

Answer (score 2):

`steady_clock::duration` is an alias for `std::chrono::duration<rep, period>` where `rep` and `period` are respective member aliases of the clock (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock).

You can check if `rep` is signed via:

```
 std::cout << std::is_signed< steady_clock::rep >::value;
```

And when it is signed, then you can call (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration/duration)

```
template< class Rep2 >
constexpr explicit duration( const Rep2& r );
```

to construct a negative `duration`. `time_point` is here `std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock,std::chrono::steady_clock::duration>` and uses the same representation of durations.